# How to define object in redux flutter app state and access the properties?

Tags: redux, dart, flutter

I define a object on my initial state, however when I try to check the state I get null, here is my AppState:

```dart
@immutable
class AppState {
  final bool isLoading;
  final int bottomNavIndex;
  final Poscomp poscomp;

  AppState({this.isLoading = false, this.poscomp, this.bottomNavIndex});

  factory AppState.loading() => AppState(
        isLoading: true,
        poscomp: Poscomp(exams: []),
        bottomNavIndex: 0,
      );

  AppState copyWith({
    bool isLoading,
    Poscomp poscomp,
    int bottomNavIndex,
  }) {
    return AppState(
      isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
      poscomp: poscomp ?? this.poscomp,
      bottomNavIndex: bottomNavIndex ?? this.bottomNavIndex,
    );
  }
}
```

The definition of `Poscomp`:

```dart
@immutable
class Poscomp {
  final List<Exam> exams;

  Poscomp({this.exams = const []});

  Poscomp copyWith({List<Exam> exams}) {
    return Poscomp(
      exams: exams ?? this.exams,
    );
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => exams.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Poscomp &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          exams == other.exams;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Poscomp{exams: $exams}';
  }
}
```

When I try to access other properties of my state it works fine, but the object always return null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently when we dispatch an action the others properties which don't have an reducer are redefined as null, then what I needed to do was:

Define a reducer for that object:

```dart
import 'package:computeiro/store/models/index.dart';
import 'package:computeiro/store/reducers/index.dart';

AppState appReducer(AppState state, action) {
  return AppState(
    isLoading: loadingReducer(state.isLoading, action),
    poscomp: poscompReducer(state.poscomp, action), //HERE
    bottomNavIndex: bottomNavReducer(state.bottomNavIndex, action),
  );
}
```

Define an new constructor for `Poscomp`:

```dart
factory Poscomp.init() => new Poscomp(
      exams: [Exam(question: 'What is somethine?', answer: Answer.A)]);
```

And call it inside `AppState`:

```dart
factory AppState.initial() => new AppState(
        isLoading: true,
        poscomp: Poscomp.init(),
        bottomNavIndex: 1,
      );
```